# How to set my vncserver listen on my Public IP , I cant use vnc viewer to connect to my server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vnc

I use netstat to see what ports are listening.The vncserver is running.,but listen on localhost,I want to make it listen on public ip ,how to do that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it in file `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` by removing from start line `-localhost` and restart the service.

Comment: I  found why  I cant connect to my server 。It‘s because I use the wrong port to connect.It must use port 1 not 5901

Comment: But thank you for helping me to know more about vnc.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong port 5901 to connect.It should use the port you used in setting the vnc server using

```
 vnserver :1
```

The port number is 1 not 5901.